Timefold: How to access ProblemFact (WorkingCalendar) from a PlanningEntity Class to Use with @CascadingUpdateShadowVariable for Effective Planning
I'm encountering an issue with accessing ProblemFact from PlanningEntity class in my Timefold solution. Here’s a summary of the situation:
Issue Description:
Variable Change: I initially faced a problem where all jobs were being assigned to a single employee when Working with VariableListener. Logging showed only employee1 in the output.
CascadingUpdateShadowVariable: I implemented @CascadingUpdateShadowVariable, which resolved the issue quickly. With this annotation, I was able to see employee1, employee2, employee3, etc., and the implementation was concise compared to using VariableListener.
Problem:
Accessing ProblemFact: In the PlanningSolution class, I have a ProblemFact that acts as a condition object (similar to WorkCalendar in TimeFold quickstart). With VariableListener, I can access this ProblemFact without issues. However, when using @CascadingUpdateShadowVariable inside the PlanningEntity class, I am unable to access the ProblemFact.
Question: Is there a way to access ProblemFact from within the PlanningEntity class when using @CascadingUpdateShadowVariable? I have seen some posts about cloning, but I am unsure how to access it from the PlanningEntity class. Is there an annotation or a specific approach to achieve this?

What do you mean by "unable to access ProblemFact"? How were you able to access it before?

In VariableListener ScoreDirector. I switched back to VariableListener and fixed all the issues and the problem solved
